# restore a statamic app from existing folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks, statamic

I need to open a directory where is installed statamic in my local macbook 
the server web open but without image css only with the text like the picture

[image]

maybe the problem is in the configuration file but i dont have idea where is in the folder app

im newbie also about laravel

sorry for the english i hope that they understand
anyone help me ?
thanks a lot

Comment: What errors in console of browser?

Comment: no error only the the images the css doesnt work, the text work